# What's the significance of OrderPart entity in moqui? What are basic differences between OrderPart and OrderItem entity?

Tags: moqui

I want to know the significance of the OrderPart entity in moqui and what are basic differences between OrderPart and OrderItem entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that OrderPart and OrderItem are similar in a way, they are both detail entities to the OrderHeader master entity. For general info on master/detail and other data model patterns see:

https://moqui.org/m/docs/framework/Data+and+Resources/Data+Model+Patterns

For more specific information about the Order data model see:

https://moqui.org/m/docs/mantle/Mantle+Structure+and+UDM/Order

The use of OrderItem and OrderPart are very different, items being the line items for the order and parts being a break down of the order under OrderHeader to allow for shipping to multiple locations on the same order, or any other business requirement for splitting orders. Order Parts are used in different ways in different companies as a generic model but you can get an idea of the fields that are intended to be different for different parts of an order by looking at the fields on OrderPart vs OrderHeader.